# window.onbeforeunload not firing in IE8 (works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

So I have been going crazy trying to figure out why the following is not firing off in IE 8 but working in the "big 3", Firefox, Chrome, and Safari

(From inside a Javascript function)

```
var popupWindow=window.open(document.location.href+kugiri+"popup_flg=1", 'mypopup','width=640,height=480');


popupWindow.onbeforeunload = function() {
    changeVideoPlayback(true);
    if(someFalseVal)
        return "oy";
    else
        return ;
};
```

(Note most of this code was just a desperate attempt to get IE to work, I really only want the

```
    changeVideoPlayback(true);
```

part to fire off.  What am I doing wrong that makes IE just refuse to execute the onunload whenever the window closes?

I should also add that I have tried onunload as well, no dice.

Comment: What does `changeVideoPlayback()` do?

Comment: Starts or stops a ustream video, but thats irrelevant, it isnt being called(I can call it from the console and it works just fine, but if I put a breakpoint in the function and close the window, I can see that it isnt being called)

Comment: `popupWindow.contentWindow=onbeforeunload=...` ?

Comment: Tried that, unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of "onbeforeunload"  use "onunload".